# can shell code inside a heredoc construction get access to its parent script's standard input?

Tags: shell, pipe

I have the following construction in a shell script `foo.sh`:

```
(tr -d \\r|bash)<<:END

echo Hello World
# more lines of arbitrary bash code here

:END
```

As far as I can tell, this sacrifices the ability of the heredocced code (where it says "arbitrary bash code") to access `foo.sh`'s standard input. In other words, if I say, for example

```
echo "something" | ./foo.sh
```

then there seems to be no way of allowing the heredocced bash code to get access to the string `"something"` - rather, the code seems to behave as if its standard input is an empty, closed file.  Is there a way round this?

[ To forestall inevitable "why would you even..." questions, the reason for using this construction in the first place is that it allows the script to run even if the file has CRLF line-endings. In reality the file has the extension `.bat` and is a double-duty cross-platform executable script that can [run from the command-line under either Windows or unix-like systems](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66812/48148) and is used for bootstrapping a larger project. For the convenience of being human-readable and -editable on new Windows systems that have nothing nicer than `notepad.exe` installed, the file is given Windows-style line endings. ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heredoc is just plain text. You turn it into a command script by feeding it into the standard input of a bash process. While that bash process is running, its standard input has been redirected (in this case to the output of the `tr` command), and that's what the `bash` process will use as its standard input. (Forgive the redundancy.) That's a general issue with running a script provided to a shell's standard input, and has very little to do with heredocs.

That's not the only way to execute a bash script. You can, for example, use a named file, even if the name is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) (assuming your driver is using `bash` or another shell which supports that syntax.) Doing that avoids the need to redirect standard input.

```
bash <(tr -d \\r <<":EOF"
  read line
  echo Hello, "$line"
:EOF
)
```

If that's too esoteric, you could copy the heredoc into a temporary file, and then source the temporary file.

Comment: Impressive—I would never have imagined this possible. Am I right in thinking `<(this)` is bash-only syntax? When I first tried this I got syntax errors—because the parent file was in fact running in a different shell, for various reasons. I guess I can change that by changing the `#!` line

Comment: @jez: It's not bash-only -- ksh and (iirc) zsh have it too -- but it is not Posix. I should have mentioned that, but you used `bash` as a tag.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine this is probably going to be the best answer. But I'll remove the bash tag and (temporarily) unaccept just to see if others have thoughts on this.

Comment: @jez: with a posix shell, use the temporary file solution in the last paragraph.